# Some Server Variables not accessible from OwinContext

Tags: .net, iis, owin, katana, server-variables

In theory the OwinContext environment should have access to the request/response information as well as server variables, although for some reason from the OwinContext I can't access some of the custom server variables that are available from the `Request.ServerVariables` collection.

What is causing this discrepancy and how should I get around it?

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into this myself. It turns out you can access a `HttpContextWrapper` from the `IOwinContext.Environment`:

```
var httpContextWrapper = owinContext.Environment["System.Web.HttpContextBase"] as HttpContextWrapper;
```

Then you can access the `Request` property:

```
httpContextWrapper.Request.ServerVariables
```

Comment: I am not sure which one is honestly better, but HttpContext.Current.Request worked as well in that context.